# Put mdadm raid's HDDs in standby after X minutes

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a RAID setup using mdadm with 4 harddrives. The server should not always run the harddrives, so I searched for a solution to put HDDs in standby and found this:

```
hdparm -S 240 /dev/sda
```

which should put drive `/dev/sda` in standby and sets auto-spindown-timer to 20 minutes, so the next time it will be idle for more than 20 minutes it will be spin down again. The output of the command also states this:

```
/dev/sdb:
 setting standby to 240 (20 minutes)
```

But in fact, the drive spins down after about 5 seconds after the last access, and

```
hdparm -C /dev/sdb
```

displays:

```
/dev/sdb:
 drive state is:  standby
```

It is impossible to access the RAID, since it is a RAID5 and data is spread among devices, so reading a file results in waking up one drive, then the second drive, but after 5 seconds the first drive was idle, it spins down again and so on...

Sometimes, if I execute `hdparm -C` to check the current status of the drive, it spins up, which is definitely not what I want, since I wanted to write a monitor script checking the status every minute or so.

Since mdadm is running and the RAID is mounted, it may be the case that mdadm is accessing the disks too often, so this may be the problem but I don't really think so.

Another question is: Is it possible to check a drive's temperature when it is in standby? Using `hddtemp` gives me `SLP` which obviously stands for standby, so using hdparm wouldn't be a solution to check for temperature in standby mode. But it may be an alternative solution for checking the status of the drive?

So there are actually three problems:

- Drive spins down too fast using `hdparm -S ...`
- Drive spins up when checking its status using `hdparm -C`
- Checking temperature of drive in standby mode isn't possible using `hddtemp`

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Spinning hard drives up and down is bad for them. You might save a tiny amount of power, but you could cost yourself a large amount of money replacing it early.

Comment: That's the reason why I don't want them to spin up and down too often. I use the RAID only as a network device for multimedia data and backups, so the drives should be in stand by most of the time. I expect the drives to spin up about 1 to 2 times a day in average. The timeout of 2 minutes is for testing purposes and will be increased to about 1 hour.

Comment: +1. I've been waiting years for someone to phrase this question well.

Comment: @tomfanning Me too, so now I did finally ;)

Comment: Spinning up twice a day is worse than letting them spin unused.

Comment: I power on my 6 years old desktop computer twice a day having 4 drives and they still live, so what? Letting them spin 24/7 would produce too much heat. I use a RAID5, so I am not very worried about the health of the drives. Even if two of them die, they only contain private multimedia stuff, no critical data.

Comment: Ah, so this is home-use stuff and not about managing computer systems in a professional capacity.

Comment: @Zoredache this is about solving the issue I described, not about why spin-down is a bad idea. And yes, this is for home-use. Data isn't very critical. Whether or not this is professional depends on the use case, and in this case I think it is more professional to save 60% energy and a lot of heat of a home server than caring about something I can't prevent totally (death of drives).

Comment: If you want your hard drives to stop spinning, there are many options. http://youtu.be/yd_O7-rqcHc?t=11s is my favourite.

Comment: @leemes "You're doing it wrong" is a valid answer in this context, as you haven't given us a reason for wanting to do something that is generally regarded as a Bad Idea with the potential to contribute to early (or at least earlier) drive failures. Like any other rotating assembly the bulk of drive's wear (and largest power inrush) happens when it has to hurl the inertial mass of the platters back up to speed from a stop. FWIW If you are *truly* concerned about power the answer I'd give you would be "Switch to 2.5" drives or SSDs".

Comment: Also, questions for home use are specifically off-topic on Server Fault (this is what [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) is for).  Accordingly I'm going to put this question out of its misery and stop the avalanche of back-and-forth comments arguing about it.  If you would like to ask about the internals of hdparm in your specific situation SuperUser or possibly [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) may be more appropriate. Please read their site FAQs before opening a question though.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Then the money would be the problem. I already decided to let the drives only spin up when I need them. This may be far less than 2 times a day, maybe even only once a week. And I can only repeat: I do not care much if in 2 years or so one drives dies. So WHERE THE HELL is the problem?

Comment: @leemes, if you really want to discuss it, drop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room). However as you've mention this is in a home setup it still remains off-topic for ServerFault.

Comment: @tomfanning Since this question isn't welcome here, I asked it again on askubuntu, where I got help very quickly: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137577/put-hdds-in-standby-after-x-minutes-using-hdparm-doesnt-work

Comment: Thank you @leemes for putting the pointer to your question over there.